# Inserting data using AJAX in Laravel results in 500 internal server error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel

My controller:

```
public function testdemo() {
    $input = Request::all();
    Studs::create($input);
    return 'successfully Inserted';
}
```

My AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insertdata() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var add = $("#add").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var dat = $("#date").val();

    alert(dat);

    $.ajax({
        type :'POST',
        url :'{{url('testdemo')}}',
        data :'_token=<?php echo csrf_token()?>',
        success :function(data) {
            alert(data);
            //$('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I wrote this code but inserting data using AJAX results in this:

> 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What is the route you are trying to post to?

Comment: Do you get any sort of stack trace in the logs on the server?

Comment: this is not correct process, you call function in url which wrong and second you send only token data

Comment: possible duplicate 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001499/laravel-ajax-insert-data-into-table-without-refreshing

Comment: Could you paste the error you're getting in your log file?

Comment: you need to post the schema for studs